# "Ronald Reagan is the devil"?

Tags: the-boondocks

In Huey's announcement in the very first scene of *The Boondocks*, he says:

> Jesus was black, Ronald Reagan was the devil, and the government is lying about 9/11

Why does he say that about Ronald Reagan?

Comment: Because that's his opinion? http://genius.com/2550739 has some "supporting evidence" to his claim, but IMHO they miss the point. "Ronald Reagan was the devil" is basically Huey contradicting the deification of Reagan by Republicans and others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He is rattling off a series of conspiracy theories that have been culturally popular at some time or another:

- Jesus was black - the "traditional" image of Jesus depicts him as caucasian, while in reality, given his nationality, he was almost certainly olive-complexioned (think Mediterranean, Arab, etc.). However, there have been [various theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_and_appearance_of_Jesus#Emergence_of_racial_theories) that he was actually of African descent and has been purposefully white washed.
- The government is lying about 9/11 - This one's probably more familiar because it's more recent. There is a huge group of "9/11 Truthers" that belive the government had a hand in the Sept. 11 attacks, or is otherwise lying about it.
- Ronald Reagan is the devil - Back when he was president, there was a fringe theory that Reagan was [actually the antichrist](http://www.666truth.org/history/antichrist-myths/articletype/articleview/articleid/901/pageid/914), based on a number of passages from the Book of Revelation. (It largely focused on the fact that his name - Ronald Wilson Reagan - had 6 letters per name, thus "666".)